# how to install Ubuntu on the Asus Fonepad me371mg?

Tags: asus

Here there was a problem, I can understand if I install Ubuntu on a tablet, if so, in what way? And how Manuals

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. Your best bet are the Nexus devices. Right now, as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install "The Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview is intended to be used for development and evaluation purposes only. It is an experimental development snapshot that can potentially brick your device. It does not provide all of the features and services of a retail phone and cannot replace your current handset..."